# CLI Progress bar with readable multi-line message/info

Tags: symfony, laravel

A portion of my Laravel app uses the cli to do batch processing. I'm trying to make a progress bar that will give useful information as to how far along in the process you are. One thing I am doing batch processing on is addresses. I'd like to format it somewhat similar to this:

```
Processing addresses...

Local Shopping Mall
123 Fake street
Cityville, USA
12345
4/378 [>---------------------------]   1%
```

After the first address, I'd like to  move the cursor back to right after 'Processing addresses...' and I'd like to overwrite the old address with the new one.

Right now, I'm getting this:

```
Processing addresses...
124 Fake street
Cityville, USA
12345

125 Fake street
Cityville, USA
12345

126 Fake street
Cityville, USA
12345

127 Fake street
Cityville, USA
12345

4/378 [>---------------------------]   1%
```

Here's the (slightly modified) code I'm using:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->info('Processing addresses...');

        $addresses = \App\Address::all();
        $bar = $this->output->createProgressBar(count($addresses));
        foreach ($addresses as $address) {
            $bar->clear();
            $this->info("\r" . $this->_getFormattedAddress($address));
            $bar->advance();
            sleep(1);
        }
    }

    private function _getFormattedAddress(\App\Address $address){
        $out = "";
        $out .= $address->address1 . "\n";
        $out .= $address->address2 . "\n";
        $out .= $address->city . "\n";
        $out .= $address->region . "\n";
        $out .= $address->iso_code . "\n";
        $out .= $address->postal_code . "\n";
        return $out;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

"\r" - return point to start line and $this->info() - add PHP_EOL to end line.

If you need return cursor to top output. I dont know Laravel can do it or not. But this class help you:

```
class OutputCliHelper
{
    protected static $lastLines = 0;

    /**
     * @param $data
     * @return string
     */
    public static function replaceSingleLine($data){
        return "\r".$data;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public static function getLastLines()
    {
        return static::$lastLines;
    }

    /**
     * @param      $data
     * @param null $lastLines
     * @return string
     */
    public static function replaceMultiLine($data, $lastLines = null)            {
        if(!is_null($lastLines)) {
            static::$lastLines = $lastLines;
        }

        $term_width = exec('tput cols', $toss, $status);
        if($status) {
            $term_width = 64; // Arbitrary fall-back term width.
        }

        $lineCount = 0;
        foreach(explode(PHP_EOL, $data) as $line) {
            $lineCount += count(str_split($line, $term_width));
        }

        $magic = '';
        // Erasure MAGIC: Clear as many lines as the last output had.
        for($i = 0; $i < static::$lastLines; $i++) {
            // Return to the beginning of the line
            $magic .= "\r";
            // Erase to the end of the line
            $magic .= "\033[K";
            // Move cursor Up a line
            $magic .= "\033[1A";
            // Return to the beginning of the line
            $magic .= "\r";
            // Erase to the end of the line
            $magic .= "\033[K";
            // Return to the beginning of the line
            $magic .= "\r";
            // Can be consolodated into
            // $magic .= "\r\033[K\033[1A\r\033[K\r";
        }
        static::$lastLines = $lineCount;

        return $magic.$data."\n";
    }
}
```

Now you need get output string (implode PHP_EOL), and call:

```
$text = "{$id} Fake street\nCityville, USA\n12345";
$progressOutputString = ...;
$yourOutputString = $text.PHP_EOL.$progressOutputString;
echo OutputCliHelper::replaceMultiLine($yourOutputString);
```

For example:

```
public function handle()
{
    $output = new BufferedOutput(); //Symfony
    $progress = new ProgressBar($output); //Symfony
    $progress->start(10);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $progress->advance();
        $tmp = explode(PHP_EOL, $output->fetch());
        $string = array_pop($tmp);
        echo static::replaceMultiLine($string.PHP_EOL.mt_rand());
    }
}
```